# How come Veerbhadra mentions Vamana avatar during his encounter with Narasimha?

Tags: shiva-purana

In Shiv Purana posted here (I think it was by Keshav Srinivasan), Veerbhadra was asking Narasimha to leave this form. He cited several reasons one of them being that even Prahalad grandson has been blessed by Vamana.

Does it mean that Lord Vishnu had Vaman and Narasimha avatar going on simultaneously? Can someone help explain.

Comment: In The Ramayana, Yuddhakhanda, Trishiras says _"sambaro devarAjena narako viSNunA yathA"_
If it was the same narakasura who was slain in The Krishnavatara, how come his name appears in The Ramavatara? Some commentators say this Naraka was not the same one who was slain by Lord Sri Krishna. Some say it was the same, so this could be interpolation.
Similarly my take, which I cannot prove obviously, accounts like these indicate possible interpolation / unauthorized edits. I will check Sri Shiva Mahapurana tomorrow and see what the verse says exactly. Easy to lose meaning in English translation

Comment: @Vidyarthi - Sure. Looking forward to see it from you. Btw , there is no confusion on Naraka. See the explanation here http://www.valmikiramayan.net/yuddha/sarga69/yuddha_69_prose.htm .

Comment: yeah that's one of the interpretations. That's what I meant in my comment saying "some commentators say this Naraka was not the same as the one who was slain by Lord Sri Krishna".

Comment: May be that's a question for other SE users - about the narakA slain by Lord Vishnu. Will post it as a question